# ParseError at [row,col]:[5,2] Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

When I build a new project every time this error pop up

> ParseError at [row, col]:[5,2]
> Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Screen shots: [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNWCR.png); [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpFLN.png)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.signsql">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SignSql">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

even when I try open merged manifest it shows UNABLE TO COMPUTE MERGED MANIFEST

and also in Design, it appears RENDER PROBLEM.

Comment: The manifest you've posted is well-formed and would not cause that XML parse error.

Comment: okay I have solved my issue just reinstall the AS and thank you 